# Can't move a gemeObject smoothly with MoveTowards or Lerp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I'm an extreme amateur with a very simple goal. Inside an OnGui i have a button. I want this button when pressed to move the gameObject it's attached to to move a distance to the right in a smooth motion. I've been successful in setting the distance i want to move to, but i cannot make the movement smooth to save my life.

```
    private void OnGUI()
{
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(165, 300, 150, 350), "right"))
    {            
        var pos = transform.position;
        float rightMovement = pos.x + 0.5f;

      Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(rightMovement, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

        while (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPosition) > 0.1f)
        {
            float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, step);
        }
        Debug.Log("Clicked rightMovement");
    }
```

(Speed = 5f) This is what i felt like got me the closest to my goal. Currently it moves the distance, but just in a single frame. I also tried to use an IEnumerator that basically has the same code inside and just call said IEnumarator from inside the OnGui, but to no avail.

Comment: The entire loop will complete within one frame as you've realized. The IEnumerator approach is on the right track. Can you post your code from that attempt?

Comment: OnGUI is called multiple times per frame. Time.deltaTime is the time between frames. That is likely what is causing it to not be smooth.

Comment: Don't use `OnGUI` it is legacy ... rather use a `UI.Button`

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is this loop

```
while (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPosition) > 0.1f)
{
    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, step);
}
```

This moves your object in one single step because no frame is rendered meanwhile. The `while` rather blocks the entire thread until it is done (which I this case is not that long) and then renders the frame when done.

Additionally as also mentioned in the comments `OnGUI` is called multiple times per frame so it gets even worse.

---

As I also commented `OnGUI` is kind of legacy and you shouldn't use it anymore except you know exactly how and what you are doing.

Rather use a [`UI.Button` in a `Canvas`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html).

---

If I see it right you want to move while the button stays pressed.

Unfortunately there is no built-in Button for handling something like "while button stays pressed" so you'ld have to use the [`IPointerDownHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html) and `IPointerUpHandler` interfaces.

Put this class on the `UI.Button` object

```
public class MoveButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    public enum Alignment
    {
        Global,
        Local
    }

    // Configure here the movement step per second in all three axis
    public Vector3 moveStep;

    // Here reference the object that shall be move by this button
    public Transform targetObject;

    // Configure here wether you want the movement in
    // - Global = World-Space
    // - Local = Object's Local-Space
    public Alignment align;

    private Button button;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        button = GetComponent<Button>();
    }

    //Detect current clicks on the GameObject (the one with the script attached)
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        // Ignore if button is disabled
        if(!button.interactible) return;

        StartCoroutine (Move());
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }

    // Actually not really needed but I'm not sure right now
    // if it is required for OnPointerExit to work
    // E.g. PointerDown doesn't work if PointerUp is not present as well
    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {

    }

    // And finally to the movement
    private IEnumerator Move()
    {
        // Whut? Looks dangerous but is ok as long as you yield somewhere
        while(true)
        {
            // Depending on the alignment move one step in the given direction and speed/second
            if(align == Alignment.Global)
            {
                targetObject.position += moveStep * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else
            {
                targetObject.localPosition += moveStep * Time.deltaTime;
            }

            // Very important! This tells the routine to "pause"
            // render this frame and continue from here
            // in the next frame.
            // without this Unity freezes so careful ;)
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively you could stick to your code but separate the button from the movement like

```
private bool isPressed;

private void OnGUI()
{
    isPressed = GUI.Button(new Rect(165, 300, 150, 350), "right");
}

private void Update()
{  
    if(!isPressed) return;

    var pos = transform.position;
    var targetPosition = pos + Vector3.right * 0.5f;

    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPosition) > 0.1f)
    {
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, step);
    }
}
```